# CMAKE: Circular ... dependency dropped

Tags: cmake

I have a 3rd-party (prebuilt) executable (named *other*) located in *imported* folder of my project's source tree. Basically, the project's structure looks like this:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── imported
│   ├── libother.so
│   └── other
└── main.cpp
```

In order for my application to operate properly, that *other* executable must be copied next to *my* executable, what I achieve with this script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(myproject)
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
set(path_in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/imported/other)
set(path_out ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/other)
add_executable(other_i IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(other_i PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${path_in})
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${path_out}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${path_in} ${path_out}
    DEPENDS other_i
    )
add_custom_target(other DEPENDS ${path_out})
add_dependencies(myexe other)
```

The problem is whenever the project is being built, on Linux, I am getting weird messages from gmake:

```
$ cmake -S . -B .build
...
$ cmake --build .build
gmake[2]: Circular CMakeFiles/other <- other dependency dropped.
gmake[2]: Circular other <- other dependency dropped.
```

While the *other* is copied all right, it is being copied ALWAYS whenever I re-issue a build command (even without any changes). This is undesirable and what is bothering me most is that it works perfectly with MSVC on Windows and also with shared libraries on Linux. E.g. this works fine:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(myproject)
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
set(path_in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/imported/libother.so)
set(path_out ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libother.so)
add_library(other_i SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(other_i PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${path_in})
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${path_out}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${path_in} ${path_out}
    DEPENDS other_i
    )
add_custom_target(other DEPENDS ${path_out})
add_dependencies(myexe other)
```

I am at wits end on what is going on. Is it a CMAKE's bug or I am missing something?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Please do not suggest using POST_BUILD on a main target, as this approach has it's own drawbacks.

Comment: `DEPENDS other_i` Why do you depend on the library?

Comment: @KamilCuk, 'DEPENDS other_i' - this is a dependency on a target, whatever it might be

Comment: But you depend on the file, not on the target `DEPENDS ${path_in}`. That command does not care about the target. Also, does _building_ `myexe` depends on the library copied to the binary dir? For me, you should create like another custom target, that depends on `myexe` being build and the library copied, these are separate unrelated actions.

Comment: It should: "If the argument is the name of a target (created by the add_custom_target(), add_executable(), or add_library() command) a target-level dependency is created to make sure the target is built before any target using this custom command." https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
add_custom_target(other DEPENDS ${path_out})
```

creates a dependency of `other` from the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/other`.
But from the view of Make these are the **same things**: both refers to the file `other` under the build directory (where `Makefile` is located). Because of that you get the message

```
gmake[2]: Circular other <- other dependency dropped.
```

The core of the problem is that unlike to CMake, Make doesn't have separation of *targets* (pure names) and *files* (located on the disk). From the view of Make all targets (even `.PHONY` ones) are files.

Using another name for target `other` (e.g. `other_exe`) would eliminate the problem.

Comment: Indeed, while this might be a bug in CMAKE, changing the target's name 'other' to something different eliminates the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in CMake! I worked around it like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(myproject)

set(path_in "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/imported/other")
set(path_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/other")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${path_out}"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_if_different "${path_in}" "${path_out}"
    DEPENDS "${path_in}"
)
add_custom_target(other_update DEPENDS "${path_out}")

add_executable(myproject::other IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(myproject::other PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${path_out}")
add_dependencies(myproject::other other_update)

add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
add_dependencies(myexe myproject::other)
```

There were a couple other issues with specifying your dependencies, so I cleaned those up. Even so, I observe that naming an executable target (even if imported) the same as the output file trips the bug. You should open an issue with CMake upstream.

In general, it is a good idea to utilize the fact that CMake always treats names containing `::` as target names.

Comment: CMake Error at ... (add_custom_target):
1>    The target name "myproject::other" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior. - MSVC